# Alternative to nested for-loop in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I came across the following (conceptually very simple) problem, and want to write code to do it, but am struggling. Let's say we have two rows of equal length, k.  Each cell of each row can be either a 0 or a 1.

For e.g., consider the following row-pair, with k = 5:  01011, 00110

Now if the two rows could freely exchange values at each cell, there would be 2^5 possible combinations of row-pairs (some of which may not be unique).  For instance, we could have 00010, 01111 as one possible row-pair from the above data.   I want to write code in Delphi to list all the possible row-pairs.  This is easy enough to do with a set of nested for-loops.  However, if the value of k is known only at run-time, I'm not sure how I can use this approach for I don't know how many index variables I would need.  I can't see how case statements will help either because I don't know the value of k.

I am hoping that there is an alternative to a nested for-loop, but any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're looking to do - some code would help me understand

Comment: Can you show your code that works for a "fixed" `k`?

Comment: Not knowing `k` until runtime is not an issue at all, as long as the rows are of equal length. Can you post what you've tried so far that you're having difficulty with? (Questions asking for code should at least include some sort of effort on your part to find a solution.)

Comment: This sounds like a Computer Science problem. I assume the two rows are part of the "test set", aren't they.

Comment: I'm sorry - it was a bit premature of me.  Let me work on this a bit more and post the question again.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user1505202 didn't rob answer the question you asked?

Comment: No, don't ask the question again! Instead, update this question.

Comment: @NGLN It's too late for that. Rob clearly put a lot of thought and effort into his answer. Changing the question nullifies that.

Comment: @David I meant to discourage and prevent user from posting the question again, which he clearly was about to. Editing is preferred over asking again. Besides, adding some tried code won't change the meaning of the post. And if the change would render already given answers useless, then there's a rollback opportunity. It's never to late to clarify a post.

Answer (score 4):

Given two vectors *A* and *B* of length *k*, we can generate a new pair of vectors *A1* and *B1* by selectively choosing elements from *A* or *B*. Let our decision to choose from *A* or *B* be dictated by a bit vector *S*, also of length *k*. For *i* in [0..*k*), when *S<sub>i</sub>* is 0, store *A<sub>i</sub>* in *A1<sub>i</sub>* and *B<sub>i</sub>* in *B1<sub>i</sub>*. If *S<sub>i</sub>* is 1, then vice versa.

We can define that in Delphi with a function like this:

```
procedure GeneratePair(const A, B: string; S: Cardinal; out A1, B1: string);
var
  k: Cardinal;
  i: Cardinal;
begin
  Assert(Length(A) = Length(B));
  k := Length(A);
  Assert(k <= 32);

  SetLength(A1, k);
  SetLength(B1, k);
  for i := 1 to k do
    if (S and (1 shl Pred(i))) = 0 then begin
      A1[i] := A[i];
      B1[i] := B[i];
    end else begin
      A1[i] := B[i];
      B1[i] := A[i];
    end;
end;
```

If we count in binary from 0 to 2<sup>*k*</sup>−1, that will give us a sequence of bit vectors representing all the possible combinations of exchanging or not-exchanging characters between *A* and *B*.

We can write a loop and use the above function to generate all 2<sup>*k*</sup> combinations:

```
A := '01011';
B := '00110';
for S := 0 to Pred(Round(IntPower(2, Length(A)))) do begin
  GeneratePair(A, B, S, A1, B1);
  writeln(A1, ', ', B1);
end;
```

That effectively uses one set of nested loops. The outer loop is the one from 0 to 31. The inner loop is the one inside the function from 1 to `k`. As you can see, we don't need to know the value of *k* in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Now that, thanks to Rob, I understand the problem, I offer this recursive solution:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

procedure Swap(var A, B: Char);
var
  temp: Char;
begin
  temp := A;
  A := B;
  B := temp;
end;

procedure Generate(const A, B: string; Index: Integer);
var
  A1, B1: string;
begin
  Assert(Length(A)=Length(B));
  inc(Index);
  if Index>Length(A) then // termination
    Writeln(A, ', ', B)
  else
  begin // recurse
    // no swap
    Generate(A, B, Index);

    //swap
    A1 := A;
    B1 := B;
    Swap(A1[Index], B1[Index]);
    Generate(A1, B1, Index);
  end;
end;

begin
  Generate('01011', '00110', 0);
  Readln;
end.
```